# How to change SYS and SYSTEM password in oracle 12c?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

Hi i am new to programming. I was trying to install oracle 12c on my windows 10. I was following the [tutorials](https://www.oracletutorial.com/getting-started/install-oracle/).  But unfortunately i missed a step. When `Database configuration Assistant` window popped up i was supposed to click on `Password Management` but instead i clicked `ok`.

[image]

So i can not access to the following step

[image]

So how do i get back this window to change `SYS` and `SYSTEM` password?

Comment: You can change SYS and SYSTEM password after installation using command-line !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

**Login as SYSDBA:**

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

OR

sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
```

**Change password using ALTER Command:**

```
SQL> ALTER USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY [password]; 
SQL> ALTER USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY [password];
```